# js file run again when file upload ajaxly

Tags: forms, ajax, javascript

I have a js file that I add it to my form in `hook_form_alter` with `drupal_add_js`, in my js I set a click handler on Html object(lets name it ".myhtml" ), everything work correctly in first load. I have a multi value image field in my form and when try to upload a image ajaxly , my js run again , and when I click on ".myhtml" my click handler called twice ( if I upload two image it fired triple and ... ).

One of my solution was first unbind then bind click,it work but I used `icheck` Jquery plugin for that  field,then when I unbind it( icheck plugin ) will not work.
So my problem is  prevent run js file to again when file uploaded by ajax.

**part of my code**
in `hook_form_alter`

```
    $scripts = drupal_add_js();
    $jspatah = drupal_get_path('module', 'tgdev') . '/tgsp.js';
    if(!isset($scripts[$jspatah])) {
        drupal_add_js($jspatah, array(
            'type' => 'file',
            'scope' => 'footer',
            'every_page' => FALSE,
            'weight' => 10,
        ));
    }
```

and part of my js file

```
 (function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.tgdev = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $(document).ready(function(){
            if($('#edit-field-images .image-preview').length==0){
            $('.form-item-field-feature-und-email .iCheck-helper ').on('click', function () {
                  if($(this).parent('.icheckbox_line').hasClass('checked')) {
                  console.log('checked');
                     getSubsAj('mail');
             });
             }
        console.log($('#edit-field-images .image-preview').length);
        });
      }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Please share the code snippet.

Comment: @NikhilM I update question with some of my code, problem is when file upoaded ajaxly, my js run  again and again.

Comment: What i suspect is the same JS loaded each time your `#ajax` gets succeeded, try moving the `.js` out from `form`

Comment: @NikhilM I think so, but I want that js file load only in that form, maybe I must achieve my job with another method ( Not add in form alter, in another way and restrict for that form)

Comment: Okay, just try adding the `.js` from module `init` or theme so that we can drill down the issue. Possible?

Comment: @NikhilM I put remove form form_alter and put it in hook_init (also cleared the cache) `function tgdev_init()
{

if(current_path()=='node/add/listing') {
    $jspatah = drupal_get_path('module', 'tgdev') . '/tgsp.js';
    drupal_add_js($jspatah, array(
        'type' => 'file',
        'scope' => 'footer',
        'every_page' => FALSE, 
        'weight' => 10,
    ));
}
 }` , but  nothing changed, when image upload ajaxly it will run again :(

Comment: You shouldn't need to mix behaviors with dociment.ready. Behaviors are kinda replacement, not wrapper for it.

Comment: @Mołot With or Without docment.ready problem exists

Comment: @Mołot because .iCheck-helper ( a class that icheck add ) not eixst ,also try `$(document).on('click','.iCheck-helper' ,function () {` but not worked on `ICheck-helper` :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve problem with this method  **in my js file** :

instead of

```
 (function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.tgdev = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $(document).ready(function(){
            if($('#edit-field-images .image-preview').length==0){
            $('.form-item-field-feature-und-email .iCheck-helper ').on('click', function () {
                  if($(this).parent('.icheckbox_line').hasClass('checked')) {
                  console.log('checked');
                     getSubsAj('mail');
             });
             }
        console.log($('#edit-field-images .image-preview').length);
        });
      }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I use

```
 (function ($) {
     $(document).ready(function(){
            if($('#edit-field-images .image-preview').length==0){
            $('.form-item-field-feature-und-email .iCheck-helper ').on('click', function () {
                  if($(this).parent('.icheckbox_line').hasClass('checked')) {
                  console.log('checked');
                     getSubsAj('mail');
             });
             }
        console.log($('#edit-field-images .image-preview').length);
        });
})(jQuery);
```

and everything work correctly !!!

Comment: it will work, but its not the drupal way.

Comment: @NikhilM Drupal way not worked :( I try your solution, icheck elements available after document ready

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Using [jQuery Once](https://github.com/RobLoach/jquery-once)

Drupal 7 integrates the Jquery Once plugin into Drupal 7 core. This plugin adds a simple class to the HTML element to ensure that the behavior is only processed one time. Here is how we would modify our JavaScript to work with the Jquery Once plugin.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.tgdev = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      if($('#edit-field-images .image-preview').length==0){
        $('.form-item-field-feature-und-email .iCheck-helper ').once('click', function () {
          if($(this).parent('.icheckbox_line').hasClass('checked')) {
            console.log('checked');
            getSubsAj('mail');
          });
      }
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Yes,I used it before but forgot it( once) , I test this but I have one problem, 
When I remove $(document),ready  icheck class not exist yet,
try to change weight but not work

`        $jspatah = drupal_get_path('module', 'tgdev') . '/tgsp.js';
            drupal_add_js($jspatah, array(
                'type' => 'file',
                'scope' => 'footer',
                'every_page' => FALSE,
                'weight' => 100,
//                'group' =>  100,
            ));`